# psexec return result of msiexec c#

Tags: c#, psexec, windows-installer, redirectstandardoutput

i'm using psexec in c# to install software on a remote machine 
so i want to get the result of installation to see if it worked 
my problem is that the standard output return only this 
[image: click here to see]

```
  Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"psexec.exe ";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\johnpc -h  -u john -p MOHAMED msiexec /i C:\indexo\installer.msi TARGETDIR=C:\MyApp\hello /quiet";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();

            if (p.HasExited)
            {
                string strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                Console.Write( strOutput);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("TIMEOUT FAIL");
            }
```

Comment: Thats partly because its /quiet ..... you told it not to say anything

Comment: msiexec does not write anything to standard output. You'll probably have to write to a log file and read it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it  , the result of msiexec is returned in the Standard error even if the installation is completed . it says that msiexec returned error with code 0  [code 0 means installation completed sucessfully ]